# Airflow job in one region submits emr job in another region

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-emr, mwaa

We plan to have one common AWS MWAA cluster in us west region which triggers emr jobs in different regions.

Is there a way to trigger a emr job in one region by an airflow job running in another region? Is it ever possible?

Answer (score 0):

Airflow doesn't care where it's being deployed. Think if you would have deployed Airflow in Google, Azure or any other service - that wouldn't have block you from triggering EMR jobs in any AWS region you wish.

Triggering EMR jobs can be done in any region you wish.
It has nothing to do with the region MWAA is set on.

You'll need to define [Aws connection](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/connections/aws.html#configuring-the-connection) for each relevant region and utilize the relevant connection with the operator.

Comment: How about databricks job?

Comment: If I were you. I will try to test if there connection between the VPC where your MWAA service runs and the VPC where EMR is running. If there is no connectivity there are several way this can be achieved like VPC peering , Transit Gateway etc. Also check the SG rules for EMR allows connectivity as well. Hope that helps.